# Elimination of if-else for improving performance in pipelined architecture

Tags: if-statement, optimization, concurrency, exception

My professor insists on writing code which is "truly sequential" by omitting use of "if-else" constructs or "looping" constructs. 

His argument is that any branch instruction causes a pipeline flush and is inefficient.

He suggested use of signals and exception handling.

Also use certain flags viz, Overflow flag, sign flag, carry flag to replace if-else conditions.

My question is whether such a program is feasible. If YES is it really efficient?
Examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of micro-optimization makes sense in highly compute intensive loops, where reducing by a few cycles can have a noticeable effect. There are a few buts:

- if the code is not mature enough, such optimization can be premature and counterproductive;
- it is of little use to optimize code that already runs fast;
- use profiling to be sure where the bottlenecks are;
- only assembly language gives you access to the arithmetic flags;
- good compilers know the tricks and do the work for you to some extent;
- if you care about branches, also care about divisions and the memory access patterns.

With the current level of sophistication of modern processors and high-level languages, be them compiled or interpreted, you have less and less control on the code actually generated.